# Call REST Service with c, Connectivity via a GSM Modem - HTTP/1.1 505

Tags: java, c, rest, tomcat, microcontroller

I have a REST web service which follows Spring MVC and deployed with Tomcat-7.0.50 
Now I want to call for that service through a embedded code in micro controller device. GSM modem is hosted with the device to establish the connectivity via GPRS.

Here is the sample C code using to call REST service deployed in tomcat server.

```
char* connect_GPRS(void)
{
int cnt=0;

printf("connecting GPRS");
send_command("AT\r");
send_command("AT+CIPCLOSE\r");
send_command("AT+CIPSHUT\r");
send_command("AT+CIPCSGP=1,\"dialoguomlab\"\r");
send_command("AT+CGATT=1\r");
send_command("AT+CIPMODE=0\r");

send_command("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"10.8.155.16\",\"8080\"\r"); // connect TCP
_delay_ms(1000);
send_command("AT+CIPSEND\r");
while ((strchr(modem_buf,'>')==NULL)&&(cnt<60)) //wait
{_delay_ms(100); cnt++; }
clr_buf();  

// send web request to the webserver
fprintf(&modem,"POST /MyService/addnums HTTP/1.1\r\n\
Host: 10.8.155.16:8080\r\n\
Content-Type: text/html\r\n\
Content-length:6\r\n\r\n\
    10,100\
    %c",26);

while(modem_buf[0]==0);  // wait for any data to come
_delay_ms(5000);
printf(modem_buf);
send_command("AT+CIPCLOSE\r");

_delay_ms(5000);
printf(modem_buf);   // check if anything in the buffer

return modem_buf;
}
```

Web service is hosted under the url `http://10.8.155.16:8080/MyService` 
(the ip 10.8.155.16 is only a sample one and not the actual one using, we can connect the tomcat server)

Here is the code of the REST service.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnums", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=text/html")
public @ResponseBody
String addNumbers(@RequestBody String request) {
    try{

    System.out.println("just enter to addnums.... " + request);

    int sum = 0;
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList(request.split(","));
    for (String s : values) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    String sumAsString = Integer.toString(sum);
    System.out.println("going to send the response");
    return sumAsString;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception occured while processing..."+e.getMessage());
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

But when call for this we are getting the error

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 04:45:27 GMT Connection: close
```

Kindly assist me to identify the root course.

Comment: what is on the server logs?

Comment: @guido I was unable to find anything on tomcat server logs.

Comment: Have a look at the access log, it will show the request as received by tomcat

Comment: @guido I couldn't find anything with 505 in the access log as I was running the server via eclipse as we are doing frquent changes(searched for the files within eclipse but not found) We monitored the request through wireshark and it says POST /MyService/addnums HTTP/1.1 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic

Comment: i can only guess it is some non-printing character/whitespace in the first line that makes tomcat not like the request. or, it might related to keep-alive; is that the first request or there are others not shown in the c code?

Comment: Yes this is the first request. C program is written by one of my colleague. Actually I am not good at C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to find an answer to my own question and posting as it may helps someone else.

We were able to catch up the request via separate TCP Server program and while debug the request line we saw device is adding another \r before each \n. then the string has \r\r\n  for all such occurrences. that was the reason for program not to work. so when change the string as this by removing \r resolved the problem.

```
    // send web request to the webserver
    fprintf(&modem,"POST /MyService/addnums HTTP/1.1\n\
    Host: 10.8.155.16:8080\n\
    Content-Type: text/html\n\
    Content-length:6\n\n\
    10,100\
    %c",26);
```